# Реализация прав на фронте

Tags: c#, mvc, frontend, role

При авторизации под разными пользователями (правами) должен отображатся разный функционал. Т е он будет не совсем разным, а например не будет каких-то кнопочек (либо они будут не активны).

В данный момент я это реализовал так:
При авторизации все права, которые есть у пользователя записываю в `cookie`, и потом я их могу на фронте вытянуть и соответсвенно отобразить тот или инной функционал.

Как это "правильно" нужно делать? Я понимаю что каждый это делает индивидуально под свою задачу, но все таки какие есть концепции решений?

Comment: правильно в куку класть только `sessionid` который по сути ключ в мапе на сервере, в которой лежат данные пользвателей, считываете на сервере эту куку, лезете в сессию и определяете какой контент надо отдать пользователю.

Comment: так же необходимо на сервере не доверять пользователям и фильтровать запросы от них, в разрезе этих ограничений, иначе это опять же дыра

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а в какой момент мне нужно "считывать" ? получается туоп каждый раз при загрузке любой страницы у меня будет доп запрос на сервак, верно я понял?

Answer (score 0):

Правильно хранить в `cookie` или `Local Storage` только токен соответствующий пользователю и по нему от сервера получать контент и/или разрешения.

> все права, которые есть у пользователя записываю в cookie, и потом я
>   их могу на фронте вытянуть и соответственно отобразить тот или иной
>   функционал.

Это огромная дыра в безопасности, т.к. `cookie` могут подменить.

Comment: а когда мне нужно полуать права по токену?? получается при каждой загрузкуе любой страницы ?

Comment: и еще такой вопрос.....я могу кудато записать просто массив ( при авторизации) , чтобы потом с помощью `razor` вытянуть этот массив - это бы решило мою проблему

Comment: Если Вы используете Razor, то у Вас все страницы по любому генерируются сервером при каждом запросе. Если используете AJAX, то там разговор отдельный.

Comment: Вся Ваша беда с авторизацией, правами и т.д. в том, что Вы, насколько я помню, используете для этих задач свой велосипед, вместо того, чтобы воспользоваться уже готовой инфраструктурой от .NET или просто промышленными стандартами.